# Inet6Address.getByName() does return (existing) IPv6 but only IPv4 address?

Tags: java, ipv6

The following always prints the first returned IPv4 address and not the first IPv6 address
although I explicitly used Inet6Adress and not InetAddress. Is this a bug in the OpenJDK 1.7.0 I use?

```
InetAddress ipv6 = Inet6Address.getByName("www.google.com");
```

How am I supposed to get one IPv6 adresse for a given host name (or NULL if none exists)?

I do not want to change the resolver preference between IPv4 and IPv6, in this case I really want to see if at least one IPv6 address exists.

It's probably doable by iterating all results of InetAddress.getAllByName() and check for any "instanceof Inet6Address" but that does not look like the supposed way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return IPv6 in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974232/return-ipv6-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Just found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974232/return-ipv6-in-java) .

I am copying textually the answer of the user Pr0gr4mm3r

`java.net.Inet6Address` does not override `getByName()`
so it will always return the specific IPv4-Address, 
unless your parameter itself is in the form of an valid IPv6-Address, in this case this method will return an Inet6Address-Object.

For example:
`getByName("stackoverflow.com")` --> Inet4Address
`getByName("2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7344")` --> Inet6Address

Comment: That answer is incorrect: Java API simply does not support IP family preference in DNS resolution.

Comment: `InetAddress.getByName("ipv6.google.com")` can return `Inet6Address` [http://rextester.com/PNY17654](Example code).

Comment: I am making reference to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974232/return-ipv6-in-java The user is giving reference that it work