# How to get IPv6 from InetAddress.getLocalHost()

Tags: java, linux, networking, network-programming

I have a dual stack Linux machine that supports both IPv4 and IPv6 .
Now my query is when ever i tried to call InetAddress.getLocalHost() it always gives me IPv4.

Can i have both IPv4 and IPv6 in InetAddress.getLocalHost() response .
If not then how will i get IPv6 address from InetAddress.getLocalHost().

Comment: see :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974232/return-ipv6-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I responded a similar question here: [How to fetch both IPv4 and IPv6 on dual stack OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798888/how-to-fetch-both-ipv4-and-ipv6-on-dual-stack-os)

In Linux, InetAddress.getLocalHost() will look for the hostname and then return the first IP address assigned to that hostname by DNS. If you have that hostname in the file /etc/hosts, it will get the first IP address in that file for that hostname.

You can use the code in the link indicated ([How to fetch both IPv4 and IPv6 on dual stack OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798888/how-to-fetch-both-ipv4-and-ipv6-on-dual-stack-os)) and then use function getIPv6Addresses in the link indicated by @Rafiq ([Return IPv6 in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974232/return-ipv6-in-java)) to obtain only the IPv6 addresses.

I hope it helps.